# App search API validation failed for my schema/Organization?

Tags: ios, markup, schema.org, facebook-opengraph, applebot

I am trying to validate my schema for organization markup. (https://search.developer.apple.com/appsearch-validation-tool)

I am using JSON-LD markup as below.

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
    {
      "@context" : "http://schema.org",
      "@type" : "Organization",
      "name" : "XYZ Pvt Ltd",
      "url" : "http://zyz.com/",
      "logo": "http://zyz.com/images/americos-logo.png",
      "contactPoint" : [{
        "@type" : "ContactPoint",
        "telephone" : "+91-79-6605-3111",
        "contactType" : "customer service"
      }],
      "sameAs" : [
        "https://www.facebook.com/xyz",
        "https://twitter.com/xyz",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/company/xyz",
        "https://plus.google.com/xyz/posts"
      ]
    }
    </script>
```

But I am getting error as follows "Could not extract image dimensions. Learn how to include image dimensions using the Open Graph Protocol."

How can I specify  logo dimensions within JSON-LD markup for logo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the testing tool only lets you validate from a URL, not from the code, from http://schema.org/Organization you can see there is no option to add logo dimension unless you use the http://schema.org/ImageObject schema which you are not using, your markup validates in the structured data linter and google's tool.

The error actually says:

Learn how to include image dimensions using the **Open Graph Protocol**

The problem is open graph, not schema.org - the og tags do not give the image size for the logo - so add them in your  tags in the  section. Facebook's open graph tool will allow you to validae them separately to the rest of the code.

See http://og.me for syntax.

**Update**

Your original error has now gone. The remaining **open graph** errors are several, including the one about your image -  your logo http://americostech.com/images/americos-logo.png is 161px by 42px, the minimum size must be 200px by 200px (or remove the `og:image` `<meta>` tag in `<head>` or use a different image)

Use [this tool's results](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Famericostech.com%2F) to view the messages, here is an example of what the problem tags should look like:

```
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:description" content="We are popular and can make YOU too. Our apps have been featured by Apple, Google and many prominent tech and lifestyle sites." />
```

For the remaining messages, most are recommendations except for Deeplinks, which depends on whether you choose facebook, twitter or another approach -  the error results page gives you links with examples and this would really need a new question being opened. The original error is now resolved.

**Update 2**

JSON-LD (and all schema.org formats) don't allow you to specify logo dimensions (or dimensions of any image)  unless you nest the http://schema.org/ImageObject inside the original, you can then set the `height`,  `width` and many other properties, use the following in place of the `"logo":` line in the original JSON-LD to do this, example taken from [google's structured data examples for a movie's image](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/actions/watch-movies). Dimensions appear to assume pixel sizes and the documentation for schema.org seems to suggest either values or values with units (eg. for Distance) are acceptable.

```
  "logo": {
"@type":"ImageObject",
"height":600,
"width":400,
"url":"http://www.hulu.com/images/124564.jpg"
},
```

Comment: I am validation through URL. I have just pasted code from my html. I have code over here http://americostech.com/

Comment: these are [your open graph errors](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Famericostech.com%2F)

Comment: Thanks @Mousey i have resolved open graph error. but still i haven't get my answer "specify logo dimensions within JSON-LD markup ?"

Comment: @kamlesh.bar updated my answer,  you must nest in the ImageObject to do this, but the error only appears due to FB wanting image dimensions, which you typically give in the <meta> tags (as per FB's own examples)